# Как улучшить шаблон проектирования Factory Method, когда разные классы имеют одинаковую реализацию интерфейса

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Для автоматизации мобильных приложений использую шаблон проектирования Factory.
Набор методов для iOS и Android одинаковый, а вот элементы объявляются по-разному. Как избежать дублирование кода?

Здесь упрощенный пример:

```
public interface FormHelper {
    void close();
}

public class AndroidForm implements FormHelper {
    private Button btnClose = new Button("//a[text()='Close']");
    @Override
    public void close() {
        btnClose.click();
    }
}

public class IOSForm implements FormHelper {
    private Button btnClose = new Button("//div[@id='close']");
    @Override
    public void close() {
        btnClose.click();
    }
}

public class FormFactory {
    public static FormHelper getForm(){
    if (x > 0) {
        return new AndroidForm();
    } else {
        return new IOSForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Абстрактный класс?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код можно вот так зарефакторить:

```
public abstract class FormHelper {
    private final Button button;

    protected FormHelper(String action) {
        button = new Button(action);
    }

    public void close(){
        button.click();
    }
}

public class AndroidForm extends FormHelper {
    private final static String action="//a[text()='Close']";

    protected AndroidForm() {
        super(action);
    }
}

public class IOSForm extends FormHelper {
    private final static String action = "//div[@id='close']";

    protected IOSForm() {
        super(action);
    }
}

public class FormFactory {
    public static FormHelper getForm(int x) {
        if (x > 0) {
            return new AndroidForm();
        } else {
            return new IOSForm();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, для реального проекта это не подходит: там много методов и много переменных типа btnClose. Передавать их все в конструкторе не вариант

Comment: @alex вы бы тогда и привели в вопросе код, приближенный к реальному.

Comment: @andreycha да. надо было, не хотел нагромождать большие куски кода

Comment: @alex ну так отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: @andreycha нашел решение, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить абстрактный класс, унаследовать от него классы android и ios, и в них добавить блок нестатической инициализации.

```
public interface FormHelper {
    void close();
}

public abstract class FormAbstract implements FormHelper{
    protected Button btnClose;
    @Override
    public void close() {
        btnClose.click();
    }
}

public class AndroidForm extends FormAbstract {
    {
        btnClose = new Button("//a[text()='Close']");
    }
}

public class IOSForm extends FormAbstract {
    {
        btnClose = new Button("//div[@id='close']");
    }
}

public class FormFactory {
    public static FormHelper getForm(){
    if (x > 0) {
        return new AndroidForm();
    } else {
        return new IOSForm();
    }
}
```